# Reset Stack Exchange password from profile doesn't work

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, login, openid

I've just tried resetting my Stack Exchange password from my profile.

Stack Overflow > my logins > Stack Exchange > change password
results in an error message about email []
(removed)
password:Invalid email []

Going to stackexchange.com seems to have worked.

Answer (score 6):

This is a weird edge-case I'm afraid. Due to a defect in the logic surrounding email address verification a few years back, a handful of [Stack Exchange OpenId](https://openid.stackexchange.com/) accounts exist *without verified emails*. When we discovered this, we did the responsible thing and stripped the addresses from these accounts; they could still be used (and were) but without an associated, verified email to pass on to clients (such as Stack Overflow) some functionality was limited - including the ability to change your password from the "my logins" screen on your site profiles.

The solution for you (and anyone else encountering this scenario) is simply to recover your account / reset your password from https://openid.stackexchange.com/ directly... Which, as it happens, is where the *old* "my logins" dialog on https://stackexchange.com/ will send you.

The final step you'll want to take to ensure that everything is normal is to log into Stack Overflow *again* using your Stack Exchange OpenID login - this will now successfully retrieve your email address and associate it with your credentials on-site.